# I want to delete the error "GET http: // localhost: 4200 / assets / i18n / 1 / fr.json 404 (Not Found)" in the console @ Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-i18n

I want to avoid the error "GET http: // localhost: 4200 / assets / i18n / 1 / fr.json 404 (Not Found)" in the console  and in the network of navigator in Angular
//**********************************custom.translate.loader.ts****************************************

```
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            this.http.get('./assets/i18n/' + loggedUser.selectedOrganizationId + '/' + lang + 
            '.json').subscribe((res: Response) => {
                observer.next(res);
                observer.complete();
            },
                error => {
                    this.http.get('/assets/i18n/default/' + lang + '.json').subscribe((res: Response) 
                      => {
                        observer.next(res);
                        observer.complete();
                    })

                }
            );
        });
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the language in app component

```js
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
constructor(private _translate: TranslateService
  ) {
    _translate.setDefaultLang('fr-CA');
  }
```

I think your url is wrong, you need to remove the json from url.
change to the below code

```js
 return Observable.create(observer => {
            this.http.get('./assets/i18n/' + loggedUser.selectedOrganizationId + '/' + lang) .subscribe((res: Response) => {
                observer.next(res);
                observer.complete();
            },
                error => {
                    this.http.get('/assets/i18n/default/' + lang + '.json').subscribe((res: Response) 
                      => {
                        observer.next(res);
                        observer.complete();
                    })

                }
            );
        });
```

Comment: Thanks surendra kumar , But, the error still exists
"zone.js:2935 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/i18n/1/fr 404 (Not Found)"